# How to open Java doc in web browser from IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14

I was studying some code in IntelliJ. Somehow I was able to open its java doc in my default browser. The address was http://localhost:63342/Assignment1.client/swagger-java-client-1.0.0-javadoc.jar/io/swagger/client/ApiClient.html?_ijt=thgua8kptouofkf2groo7qlsvk#ApiClient--

and

http://localhost:63342/Assignment1.client/swagger-java-client-1.0.0-javadoc.jar/overview-summary.html

However, I forgot how I opened this doc the very first time. Does anyone know how? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shift + F1, from [the doc](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/viewing-reference-information.html#external-docs) will

> view documentation for a symbol at the caret in a web browser